# Jquery Ajax post using .serialize() throws 500 Internal Error

Tags: jquery, serialization, post, internal

I am trying to do a simple ajax form post of all the form fields. 
It posts the fields, but throws an error. I checked in firebug on firefox and it shows an **"500 Internal Error"**

=========

## **HTML**

```
<form action="showResult.php" id="ShowResult">
  <input type="hidden" name="price" value="$110.99" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="English" />
  <input type="hidden" name="course" value="Course" />
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://localhost/result.html" >
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="pop30387" />

  <input type="button" id="postForm" value="Add items" />
</form>
```

=========

## **Script**

```
$("#postForm").click(function() {
    $.post($('form').attr('action'), $('form').serialize());
});
```

Comment: i have updated the question with wat i have tried. Hope that helps.

Comment: What do you get when you alert $('form').serialize()?  What is alert( typeof($('form').serialize()) ); ?  Make sure the data you're sending is a map or a String, you may even want to hard code some data in there as a placeholder for the form, just so you can break down your problem and start ruling things out:  Server issue, not sending a string or map, problem with AJAX function, etc.

Comment: This looks to me like a server side problem. The JS looks good.

Comment: Yes Jmort253 said it right. It was a Server side problem. Sorry guys posted the comment late :(